# Python: While reading the file and counting the words in a line, I want to count words coming between " " or ' ' as a single word

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a file in which I have to count the number of words in each line, but there is a trick, whatever comes in between ' ' or " ", should be counted as a single word.

Example file:

```
TopLevel  
    DISPLAY "In TopLevel. Starting to run program"  
    PERFORM OneLevelDown  
    DISPLAY "Back in TopLevel."  
    STOP RUN.
```

For the above file the count of words in each line has to be as below:

```
Line: 1 has: 1 words  
Line: 2 has: 2 words  
Line: 3 has: 2 words  
Line: 4 has: 2 words  
Line: 5 has: 2 words
```

But I am getting as below:

```
Line: 1 has: 1 words  
Line: 2 has: 7 words  
Line: 3 has: 2 words  
Line: 4 has: 4 words  
Line: 5 has: 2 words
```

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

srch_dir = r'C:\Users\sagrawal\Desktop\File'

onlyfiles = [srch_dir+'\\'+f for f in listdir(srch_dir) if isfile(join(srch_dir, f))]

for i in onlyfiles:
index = 0
    with open(i,mode='r') as file:
        lst = file.readlines()
        for line in lst:
            cnt = 0
            index += 1
            linewrds=line.split()
            for lwrd in linewrds:
                if lwrd:
                    cnt = cnt +1
            print('Line:',index,'has:',cnt,' words')
```

Comment: You need to write a parser that recognizes quotes and treats them as creating a single word. There's nothing built-in that does this.

Comment: you could use regular expressions `"(.*?)"`

Answer (score 2):

**If you only have this simple format** (no nested quotes or escaped quotes), you could use a simple regex:

```
lines = '''TopLevel  
    DISPLAY "In TopLevel. Starting to run program"  
    PERFORM OneLevelDown  
    DISPLAY "Back in TopLevel."  
    STOP RUN.'''.split('\n')

import re
counts = [len(re.findall(r'\'.*?\'|".*?"|\S+', l))
          for l in lines]
# [1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

If not, you have to write a parser

Comment: You might want to look into triple quotes and the use of `r` strings to guard the backslashes against being parsed by Python. The bare `\w` is expected to become a syntax error in the future. Try `r"""'.*?'|".*?"|\w+"""` though I would definitely recommend `[^']*` and `[^"]*` over `.*?`

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the suggestions. I know about triple quotes (used them in the answer :p). Why do you recommend the `[^']*` instead of non-greedy matching?

Comment: It says what you _actually_ mean. If there _are_ nested or unpaired quotes, the regex engine will break out of them to reach a match if you let it. That can be frustrating and hard to debug.

Comment: I see your point regarding explicitness, however I fail to find an example where it would behave differently.

Comment: I can't immediately find one, either, but that only means that if the regex engine finds one we'll both be stumped.

Comment: Thanks @mozway for your suggestion.
there is an issue, while reading the line it breaks the word in two if encounters '-' in between. Like if there is a word PROGRAM-ID, above regex reading it as 2 words.
Also your code gave me an idea how to achieve my requirement, as I need the split words to, so what I will do , I will first check for " " or ' ' in a line using if and regex and if yes, then will remove all the spaces from the string in between ' ' or " ", and then will split the line as doing now.
Could you please help me in doing this, as I am new to r egex

Comment: @S.Agrawal sure you can use `\S` in place of `\w` to match the non-space characters, I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a not regex solution, this is my method for you:

```py
# A simple function that will simply count words in each line
def count_words(line):
    # Check the next function
    line = manage_quotes(line)
    words = line.strip()
    # In case of several spaces in a row, We need to filter empty words
    words = [word for word in words if len(word) > 0]
    return len(words)

# This method will manage the quotes
def manage_quotes(line):
    # We do not mind the escaped quotes, They are like a simple char
    # Also since the changes will be local we can replace words in line
    line = line.replace("\\\"", "Q").replace("\\\'", "q")

    # As all words between 2 quotes act as one word we can replace them with 1 simple word and we start with `"`
    # This loop will help to find all quotes in one line
    while True:
        i1 = line.find("\"")
        if (i1 == -1): # No `"` anymore
            break
        i2 = line[i1+1:].find("\"") # Search after the previous one
        if (i2 == -1): # What shall we do with not paired quotes???
            # raise Exception()
            break
        line = line[:i1-1] + "QUOTE" + line[i2:]
    # Now search for `'`
    while True:
        i1 = line.find("\'")
        if (i1 == -1): # No `'` anymore
            break
        i2 = line[i1+1:].find("\'") # Search after the previous one
        if (i2 == -1): # What shall we do with not paired quotes???
            # raise Exception()
            break
        line = line[:i1-1] + "quote" + line[i2:]
    
    return line
```

This is how this method works, For example, You have a line like this `DISPLAY "Part One \'Test1\'" AND 'Part Two \"Test2\"'`

At first, we remove escaped quotes:
`DISPLAY "Part One qTest1q" AND 'Part Two QTest2Q'`

Then we replace double quotations:
`DISPLAY QUOTE AND 'Part Two QTest2Q'`

Then the other one:
`DISPLAY QUOTE AND quote`

And now we count this which is 4

Comment: This is not perfect yet and might break in some cases like not escaping `"` between 2 `'` but you can add a check and fix it

Comment: Thanks @Ashenguard
But along with the count, I want the word also.. So instead of replacing the string between " " or ' ', I need to remove all the spaces (delimiters) from the string between  " " or ' ', and then will Split it to read and count the words.
Could you please help me with the code for finding the ' ' or " ", and then trim all the spaces in between them in a line

Comment: In the code where I replace them you can do whatever you want, Just for counting replace it with a word

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without regex if you keep some marker if you are inside a quoted area or not.

- `str.split()` - splitts at spaces, returns a list
- `str.startswith()`
- `str.endswith()` - takes a (tuple of) string(s) and returns True if it starts/ends with (any of) it

Code:

```
# create input file
name = "file.txt"
with open(name, "w") as f:
    f.write("""TopLevel  
    DISPLAY "In TopLevel. Starting to run program"  
    PERFORM OneLevelDown  
    DISPLAY "Back in TopLevel."  
    STOP RUN.""")

# for testing later
expected = [(1,1),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2)]  # 1 base line/word count

# program that counts words
counted = []
with open(name) as f:
    for line_nr, content in enumerate(f,1): # 1 based line count
        splt = content.split()
        in_quotation = []
        line_count = 0
        for word in splt:
            if not in_quotation:
                line_count += 1  # only increments if list empty
            if word.startswith(("'",'"')):
                in_quotation.append(word[0])
            
            if word.endswith(("'","'")):
                in_quotation.pop()
        counted.append((line_nr, line_count))
            
print(expected)
print(counted)
print("Identical: ", all(a == expected[i] for i,a in enumerate(counted)))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2)]
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2)]
Identical: True
```

You can tinker with the code - currently it does not well behave if you space out your " - it does not know if something ends or starts and both tests are True.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code attached above doesn't care about `'` or `"`.
And here is the definition of `str.split` in Python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split).

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].

Code:

```
input_str = '''TopLevel  
    DISPLAY "In TopLevel. Starting to run program"  
    PERFORM OneLevelDown  
    DISPLAY "Back in TopLevel."  
    STOP RUN.'''

input_str_list = input_str.split('\n')
print(input_str_list)


def get_trick_word(s: str):
    num = 0
    quotation_list = []
    previous_char = ' '
    for c in s:
        need_set_previous = False
        if c == ' ' and len(quotation_list) == 0 and previous_char != ' ':
            num = num + 1
        else:
            has_quato = len(quotation_list)
            if c == '\'' or c == '"':
                if len(quotation_list) != 0 and quotation_list[-1] == c:
                    quotation_list.pop()
                else:
                    quotation_list.append(c)
            if has_quato and len(quotation_list) == 0:
                num = num + 1
                need_set_previous = True

        previous_char = c
        if need_set_previous:
            previous_char = ' '
    if previous_char != ' ' and len(quotation_list) == 0:
        num = num + 1
    return num


result = [get_trick_word(s) for s in input_str_list]
print(result)
```

And the result is:

```
# ['TopLevel  ', '    DISPLAY "In TopLevel. Starting to run program"  ', '    PERFORM OneLevelDown  ', '    DISPLAY "Back in TopLevel."  ', '    STOP RUN.']
# [1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: This is not wrong per se, but it doesn't really answer the question at all.

Comment: Code is attached.